How to automate notebook execution in Azure Data Factory
how are you, I have 14 notebooks that run on data bricks in this way, the main notebook named batch_main_dwh_risk invokes another notebook called functions, and this last one invokes the other 12 notebooks that do data processing, within the main notebook. I extract from a cosmos 1000 files of the form "fg000012" which they pass as arguments to my other 12 functions, I take this to the data factory and do it the way it is in the image, my questions are, is that correct? How to do it? Is there any other correct way to upload the notebooks and allow me to reduce the time it takes to process the data in databricks?
I did this
enter image description here

From the image you provided, it looks like you are using a Databricks Notebook activity in Data Factory to run the main notebook, which then invokes the other 12 notebooks. Passing the files as arguments to the functions within the main notebook is a valid approach only. But to simplify this, you can run all the notebooks from the single notebook using azure databricks run command itself and call the main notebook using azure data factory. This will remove using many databricks activity in ADF.
Syntax for run command:
run(path: String, timeout_seconds: int, arguments: Map): String
This method is available in dbutils.notebook. For your case, you can write for loop statement to execute all 12 notebook activity with the single run statement by using parameters.
Reference: Run a Databricks notebook from another notebook - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn

Please avoid answering off-topic questions. There's nothing but a set of requirements posted by the OP. It's also an open-ended question.
